# Why do I have to cancel OpenFileDialog twice for it to close

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

Here is the code:

```
  Private Sub btn_selectfile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_selectfile.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'some code here
    ElseIf OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        OpenFileDialog1.Dispose()
    End If

End Sub
```

It also happens if I reverse them and put the `DialogResult.OK` in the `ElseIf` when selecting a file.

How shall I proceed? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ShowDialog` once, save the result, and then check it. Currently, you're calling `ShowDialog` twice, which shows the dialog to the user twice.

```
Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    'some code here
ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
    OpenFileDialog1.Dispose()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, when you cancel the dialog, you want to exit procedure. In this case you just need to check if the result is `Cancel`:

```
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel Then Exit Sub
```

After that line the result is OK, so you can safely get file path.